# Reshaping Data with values in variable names

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a very wide dataset (2000+ variables) that I'm trying to make tidy but I am getting stuck trying to pull out a value from the variable name.  If I have a variable that is `"E1Time1_Date"` I'd like to reshape it to be three variables: `E=1`, `Time=1`, and `Date`=the original date value.

Is this even possible? I've tried to use `gather()` but am guessing there is a step I need to do first that I am missing. Thank you for your help!

[image]

And here is the sample dataset if anyone wanted to make the magic happen:

```
structure(list(ID = c(123, 225), UnrelatedV1 = c("Unrelated1", 
"Unrelated1"), UnrelatedV2 = c("Unrelated2", "Unrelated2"), E1T1_Date = structure(c(1506816000, 
1513296000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    E1T1_v1 = c(10, 20), E1T1_v2 = c(20, 20), E1T1_v3 = c(30, 
    20), E1T1_v4 = c(40, 20), E1T2_Date = structure(c(1512086400, 
    NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), E1T2_v1 = c(10, 
    NA), E1T2_v2 = c(10, NA), E1T2_v3 = c(10, NA), E1T2_v4 = c(10, 
    NA), E2T1_Date = structure(c(1522540800, 1525132800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), E2T1_v1 = c(10, 20), E2T1_v2 = c(20, 
    20), E2T1_v3 = c(10, 20), E2T1_v4 = c(10, 20), E2T2_Date = structure(c(1533859200, 
    NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), E2T2_v1 = c(10, 
    NA), E2T2_v2 = c(30, NA), E2T2_v3 = c(10, NA), E2T2_v4 = c(10, 
    NA)), .Names = c("ID", "UnrelatedV1", "UnrelatedV2", "E1T1_Date", 
"E1T1_v1", "E1T1_v2", "E1T1_v3", "E1T1_v4", "E1T2_Date", "E1T2_v1", 
"E1T2_v2", "E1T2_v3", "E1T2_v4", "E2T1_Date", "E2T1_v1", "E2T1_v2", 
"E2T1_v3", "E2T1_v4", "E2T2_Date", "E2T2_v1", "E2T2_v2", "E2T2_v3", 
"E2T2_v4"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: In the dput, there are column `E1T1_v1, E1T1_v2 etc`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a mix of numeric and date values, which will make gathering a little tricky.  One way to do it is to convert dates to numeric for now, then you can change them back once you get to your final format.  This should get you started.

```
library(tidyverse)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -2L))
data %>%  
  #convert dates to numeric so we can gather them in the same column
  mutate_if(is.POSIXct, as.integer) %>%
  gather(-ID, -contains("Unrelated"), key = variable, value = value) %>% 

  #add an underscore between E and T to make separating them easier
  mutate(loc = gregexpr("T", variable)[[1]],
         variable = paste0(substr(variable, 1, loc - 1), "_",
                           substr(variable, loc, nchar(variable)))) %>% 
  select(-loc) %>% 

  #separate into three distinct columns
  separate(variable, into = c("E", "T", "vDate"), sep = "_")

# A tibble: 40 x 7
ID      UnrelatedV1 UnrelatedV2     E     T vDate      value
<dbl>       <chr>       <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1   123  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1  Date 1506816000
2   225  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1  Date 1513296000
3   123  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v1         10
4   225  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v1         20
5   123  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v2         20
6   225  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v2         20
7   123  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v3         30
8   225  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v3         20
9   123  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v4         40
10   225  Unrelated1  Unrelated2    E1    T1    v4         20
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That works perfectly, but I am not able to turn the date back into a regular date format. My favorite as.Date(data$Date,"%m/%d/%Y") turns all the dates to NA.

Comment: The "dates" are in seconds, so you'll need to convert them to days and specify the origin date.  Try this: `as.Date(data$Date / (24*60*60), origin = "1970-01-01")`